# Fixed header asp.net for resolution 1024*768

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

This might have asked a hundred times.But i cannot able to achieve when i change my screen resolution.I have GridView(ASP.Net) i need to make the header static[Freeze].I have seen and implemented many examples in CSS .In CSS i tried to make the position to absolute.Header is kinda fixed but allignment between header and column was missing.

Then i found these Example
1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61775/Grid-View-with-Fixed-Header
2. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-freeze-ASP.Net-Gridview-header-using-JavaScript.aspx
 both are using js.and its looking fine.I found the div is not responsive .SO i edited the code from 'PX' to my body column '%' .Even though the div is responsive the alignment for the grid is missing when i shrink the grid.I have two screen resolutions when i change my screen resolution also the alignment is gone.

Is there any suggestion on aligning the columns and headers grid.

Regards,
Prakash Rajan

Comment: some code and efforts please

Answer (score 0):

```
function default() { 
   var width=window.innerWidth; 
   $("#header").css("width",width); 
}
```

Now call the javascript function on Body Load. For example

```
<body onload="default()"><div id="header"></div>
```

Use your CSS for displaying with margin 0 and your required height. For example,

```
#header{margin:0 auto; height:50px; background:#000;}
```